# Ally Phone Voice Search problem

Tags: lg-vs740

I have an old Verizon Ally Android phone that keeps popping up a prompt "Try saying 'call john doe.mobile phone'" literally every half second to the point I can't even reach the settings screen to attempt to disable Voice Search. The factory reset does not help. Is there a way I can fix this somehow?

Comment: Try wiping the cache partition

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try wiping your cache partition:

- Turn off your device
- Press a combination of <kbd>Vol +</kbd>  + <kbd>Vol -</kbd> +  <kbd>Power key</kbd> buttons and hold them down.
- Release only the <kbd>Power</kbd> button when the device vibrates
- Release the other buttons when the **Recovery Menu** screen appears
- Using the <kbd>Vol +</kbd>/<kbd>Vol -</kbd> buttons to navigate, select **Wipe cache partition**
- Press the <kbd>Power key</kbd> , which will act the enter key on your keyboard.
- Wait for the process to finish.
- You can then reboot the device and see if the issue is  fixed
  .

Comment: thanks. I had to do down Volumn down, Send (button to left of home), menu, and end (power button) until LG shows then
release to get ClockworkMod Recovery v2.5.07 menu [see](http://awgjournal.blogspot.com/2017/07/replacing-rom-on-ally-lg-vs740.html)